# Using a const instead of values from database in Sequelize Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, roles, user-roles

I'm working on a project that has some users and roles. I want to add association (belongsToMany) on users and roles. I'm using MySQL database and users are stored in users table. Currently i'm storing roles in database as well but i want roles to be stored in a file instead of database. Is there a way i could use a const instead of table from database.

**index.js file:**

```
...
db.user = require("./user.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.role = require("./role.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.role.belongsToMany(db.user, {
  through: "user_roles",
  foreignKey: "roleId",
  otherKey: "userId"
});
db.user.belongsToMany(db.role, {
  through: "user_roles",
  foreignKey: "userId",
  otherKey: "roleId"
});
```

**role.model.js file**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define("role", {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });

  return Role;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is eliminate the Role table, and just create a UserRole table with a belongsTo() association to the User table. (And associate User to it by using hasMany())

You could then make the "name" column in UserRole have the [ENUM datatype](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/other-topics/other-data-types/#enums), and have the model draw the values available in that ENUM from reading the file in the file system. (Alternately, you can hard-code the values into the ENUM and that would be the "file" where you're updating possible role names)

I'm not totally sure what problem this is looking to solve, though. This seems like it would lead to a decrease in performance overall, though it WOULD eliminate the need for a Many-to-Many relationship that can be frustrating to work with.